# Errors with outputting a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, sorting

I'm having an issue with outputting the results of a bunch of functions I have. Any info is greatly appreciated because I've been stuck for hours.

Error:

```
minNum = theArray[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Desired Output:

```
The original array was:
[22, 49, 80, 4, 53, 31, 6, 30, 61, 87]
The maximum value is: 87
The minimum value is: 4
The total value is: 423
The average value is: 42.3
The sorted array is:
[4, 6, 22, 30, 31, 49, 53, 61, 80, 87]
```

Functions: 
randIntArray - populates an array of random integers (to test with).
getInt(prompt) - Tries to get an integer from the user 10x.
getData() - Performs the loop 10x using getInt to store integers into an array (userIntList).
swap - Swap routine for list.
sortArray - Sorts using the swap routine.
displayArray - Prints the array.
maxValue - Finds the max in list (not using python built in functions).
minValue - Finds the min in list (not using python built in functions).
aveValue - Finds the ave # in list (not using python built in functions).
totalValue - Finds the total # of the integers in the list (not using python built in functions)
dataOut(theArray) - Prints the values listed above.
processInput(theArray) - Uses dataOut, sort, and prompts the lists in unsorted and sorted form.
unitTest - uses the random integer function to test and prints the results.

```
import random

def randIntArray():
    randomList = []
    randomList = random.sample(range(1, 101), 10)
    return randomList

def getInt(prompt):
    # Function to call when asking for the A and B values later.
    try:
        x = input(prompt)
        y = int(x)
        return y  
    except:
        print("That was not an integer. Please enter an integer. ")


def getData():
    userIntList = []
    for i in range(10):
        userNum = getInt("Please enter value number : ")
        userIntList.append(userNum)
    return userIntList


def swap(a, j, k):
    temp1 = a[j]
    a[j] = a[k]
    a[k] = temp1

def sortArray(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for k in range(len(a) - 1):
            first = k
            second = k + 1

            if (a[first] > a[second]):
                # Uses Swap function
                swap(a, first, second)

def displayArray(theArray):
    outList = theArray
    return outList

def maxValue(theArray):
    maxNum = 0
    for i in theArray:
        if i > maxNum:
            maxNum = i
    return maxNum

def minValue(theArray):
    minNum = theArray[0]
    for i in theArray:
        if i < minNum:
            minNum = i
    return minNum

def totalValue(theArray):
    aTotal = 0
    for s in theArray:
        aTotal += s
    return aTotal

def aveValue(theArray):
    aTotal = totalValue(theArray)
    aAverage = aTotal / len(theArray)
    return aAverage

def dataOut(theArray):
    print("The maximum value is: " + str(maxValue(theArray)))
    print("The minimum value is: " + str(minValue(theArray)))
    print("The total value is: " + str(totalValue(theArray)))
    print("The average value is: " + str(aveValue(theArray)) + "\n")

def processInput(theArray):
    print("The original array was:\n " + str(displayArray(theArray)) + "\n")
    dataOut(theArray)
    sortArray(theArray)
    print("The sorted array is:\n " + str(displayArray(theArray)))

def unitTest():
    print("Running test . . .")
    randIntArray()
    theArray = randIntArray()
    processInput(theArray)
    print("\n Finished test . . .")

def main():
    unitTest()
    theArray = []
    done = False
    while not done:
        proceedQ = input("Would you like to enter 10 numbers <y/n>? ")
        if proceedQ == "y":
            getData()
            processInput(theArray)
        if proceedQ != "y":
            done = True


main()
```

Once again thank you all that participate you guys are angels.

- Bar

Comment: May be you meant to store the values returned by `getData()` into the varibale `theArray`. So, your `theArray` as of now blank but in function `minValue()` you are trying to access the first element. That is why the error is thrown

Comment: Your code is not Python idiomatic. Underscores are preferred to CamelCase in Python. There's no need for statement `randomList = []` in the `randIntArray` function (which is better to be named `generate_random_array`. Also, this function can be replaced entierly by call `random.sample(range(1, 101), 10)`, there's no need for extra function - it adds absolutely no value to your code.

Comment: `displayList` function also does effectively nothing. There're built-in `min` and `max` functions in python. Variables like `aTotal`, `theName` are weird-looking and hard to type, you'll never find prefixes like these in real production python code. I suggest you to start with reading Python Tutorial to understand the basics and PEP-8 to learn standard Python coding style.

Answer (score 0):

In `main()` when you call `getData()`, it does not assign the returned `userIntList` to the `theArray`

updated `main()` code:

```
def getData():
    userIntList = []
    for i in range(10):
        userNum = getInt("Please enter value number : ")
        userIntList.append(userNum)
    return userIntList

def main():
    unitTest()
    theArray = []
    done = False
    while not done:
        proceedQ = input("Would you like to enter 10 numbers <y/n>? ")
        if proceedQ == "y":
            # Assign the returned list from getdata() to theArray
            theArray = getData() 
            processInput(theArray)
        if proceedQ != "y":
            done = True
```

Answer (score 0):

In `main()` when you are calling the function `getData()` you are not capturing the result returned by it. So, as your `theArray` is initialized as `[]` it is passed into `minValue()` via `processInput()` with same value i.e `[]`. But inside `minValue()` you are trying to access the first element when there is no element present in `theArray`. You need to do this in `main()` -

```
theArray = getData()
```

Also in python, you don't need a separate function to do swapping. It can be done easily like this -

```
b, a = a, b
```

Even you don't need to do the sorting yourself. Try to use python provided tools and functions

Same goes for finding maximum and minimum of a list